# ItemCommand in repeater in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation, itemcommand, data-controls

I want to click on a hyperlink in a row in the repeater that will navigate me to another page
pls let me know how to use **ItemCommand** in the ASP.net **repeater** control

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpMeetings" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsMeetings">   <ItemTemplate>
<li class="list-group-item">
<h4><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" DataNavigateUrlFields="MeetingID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Forms/Meeting.aspx?meetingID={0}"
  Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:HyperLink></h4>
   <p class="pull-right">Status: <strong>'<%# Eval("Status") %>'</strong></p>
   <p><strong>Date:</strong> '<%# Eval("FinalDecidedTime") %>'<strong>Time:</strong>  - Organized by: '<%# Eval("Organizer") %>'</p>
     </li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: did you tried any thing and checked the above code whether it is giving any error or not ??

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you shouldn't need the ItemCommand. Just append the MeetingID to the NavigateUrl in the Mark-Up.

Comment: MeetingID is Dynamic I changed my code as below but still navigation does not occur  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" DataNavigateUrlFields='<%# Eval("MeetingID") %>' DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Forms/Meeting.aspx?meetingID={0}"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:HyperLink>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved using Link Button with command name and argument instead of Hyperlink

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnMeetingTitle" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MeetingID") %>' CommandName="Open" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:LinkButton></h4>
```

and in the code behind

```
    protected void rpMeetings_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Forms/Meeting.aspx?meetingID=" + Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
}
```